# How can I control (play, pause, next track, previous track) any other music player from my own Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, openai-api

Like I have an app on Playstore Achivie (`https://achivie.com`) which is made on Flutter. Now I want to implement a feature where user can control the playing music. Like google maps. If the device is playing any music from any music player, it will show everything about that music. So want to implement that feature in my Flutter App.

I tried every possible ways which are given by ChatGPT, Bard, BingAI, but nothing works.